# PhpStorm и deploy по FTP

Tags: phpstorm, ftp, контроль-версий

Здравствуйте, меня интересует есть ли у phpstorm возможность решить следующую задачу. Есть проект (работаем по FTP, др. возможности нет), создаем его в phpstorm, указываем сервер и тд, все скачивается, мы редактируем и отлаживаем все на своем локальном сервере, потом жмем кнопочку что-то типа "deploy" и все измененные (только те что были отредактированы) файлы заливаются на сервер. Т.е. ненужно каждый раз выгружать файл на прод после нажатия ctrl+s, нужно один раз когда мы закончим работу над доработкой.

Так же, интересно, если например я поработал с проектом, потом после меня кто-то другой что-то изменял, я включаю phpstorm и он узнает что на сервере кто-то что-то менял? Загрузит или предложит загрузить обновленные файлы?

p.s. сейчас подбираю ide, многие хвалят phpstorm, но всегда работал с git и подобных вопросов никогда не возникало, сейчас вот нужно по ftp поработать, может ли phpstorm решить описанные мной задачи? если да, то подскажите как все сделать, если нет - то подскажите ide которая это сможет сделать.

Всем спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Функции отравки набора измененых файлов без участия VCS нету. Подключайте ваш любимый VCS и после коммита отправляйте все на сервер.

## [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. FTP протокол вам ни как не позволет узнать этого, в конце концов он транспорт и не более. Возможно если бы во время работы через PHPSTORM, он отправлял на сервер файл-слепок с историей изменений, а другой бы человек аналогично с PHPSTORM вытагивал бы его, это возможно работало бы, но у PHPSTORM нету подобного функционала. Опять таки, VCS вам поможет. Естественно другой человек должен так же совместный с вами репозиторий.

Answer (score 1):

вопрос, как я понимаю, не столько в *выборе* инструмента, сколько в *организации* процесса.

очень хорошо, мне кажется, если круг лиц, имеющих право записи в *docroot* «боевого» сервера, ограничен.

но независимо от того, ограничен такой круг или нет, имеющим такое право неплохо бы выработать и придерживаться некоего свода формальных правил.

в частности, например:

- всегда извещать других коллег о вносимых изменениях *до* их внесения;
- документировать *все* вносимые изменения;
- организовать и поддерживать в порядке какую-то централизованную «точку» накопления этих изменений (и их описаний);
- рассматривать внесение изменений в *docroot* «в обход» этой точки как экстра-ординарное и чрезвычайное событие.

для выполнения части из озвученных правил может помочь использование доступного всем участникам процесса репозитория с контролем версий.

а конкретные *инструменты* — это уже частность, и, по моим наблюдениям, нередко их выбор — просто дело вкуса или имеющегося опыта использования.